# Examples of unbounded approximate units in $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Sometimes I see the requirement that approximate units $(u_\lambda)_\lambda$ in $C^*$-algebras must be eventually bounded, that means for some $C>0$ there is a $\lambda_0$ such that $\|u_\lambda\|<C$ for all $\lambda\ge\lambda_0$. Yet I can not come up with an example of an approximate unit that is not eventually bounded, so I'm asking for an example here. Bonus points when the approximate unit is a sequence and not just a net.

For this question I define an approximate unit of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ as a net $(u_\lambda)_\lambda$ in $A$ such that $u_\lambda a\to a$ and $a u_\lambda\to a$ for all $a\in A$.

I have looked at a few $C^*$-algebras I know:

- $C_0(\mathbb R)$: I'm quite positive that all approximate units are bounded here, but I have not worked out the details yet.
- $C_0(X)$ (and therefore all commutative $C^*$-algebras): I guess only something considerably larger than $X=\mathbb R$ can work, maybe $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$.
- group algebras $C^*(G)$: With the multiplication being a form of convolution my guess is that all approximate units converge to some "dirac" function with the weight being centered at the unit element of $G$. My gut feeling tells me again that these converge to $1$ in norm, but I could very well be wrong.
- compact operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal K(H)$. The projections on finite subspaces are an approximate unit (bounded by 1).
- General case: Some $C^*$-subalgebra $A\subset\mathcal B(H)$.

Comment: Shouldn't this follow from the uniform boundedness principle?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $u_\lambda a \to a$ in norm implies that $u_\lambda a$ is eventually bounded and therefore for every $a$ the operator $M_{\lambda}$ given by $a \mapsto u_\lambda a$ satisfies that $M_\lambda(a)$ is bounded. But, by the Uniform Boundedness Principle, that holds iff $M_{\lambda}$ is bounded. Since we are in a $C^\ast$ algebra, the norm of $a \mapsto u_\lambda a$ coincide with the norm of $u_\lambda$.

There are indeed Banach algebras without bounded approximations.

Comment: I see how to use that argument to show that all approximate unit sequences are bounded (which is quite nice already), but how do we get pointwise boundedness $\sup_\lambda \|M_\lambda(a)\|<\infty$ for all $a\in A$? I only see "eventual" pointwise boundedness, that means for all $a$ there is a $\lambda_0$ with $\sup_{\lambda\ge\lambda_0} \|M_\lambda(a)\|<\infty$. Is that sufficient for some form of uniform boundedness theorem?

Comment: The argument in this answer works for sequences, because then the convergence $M_\lambda a\to a$ guarantees that $\{M_\lambda a\}_\lambda$ is bounded, and then the UBP does the rest. But it doesn't work for nets.

Comment: Yes, Martin remark is correct. I would say that approximate units are also bounded in the case of nonseparable $C^\ast$-algebras but it does not follow automatically from the argument.